# Lasso logistic model: Interpretation of beta values

Tags: r, interpretation, lasso

I have problems to interpret my results by lasso logistic model. I use the code `cv.glmnet(x=X, y=Y, family=binomial, type.measure="auc", alpha=1)` where `x` and `y` are a dummy variables. After choosing a model by determining `lambda` by `lambda.min`, some beta values are set to zero. These are not meaningful to include and are therefore set to zero. But I do not know, how to interpret the remaining beta values. When $\beta_i$ is, for example, equal to 0.5, how can I interpret this result?